# Sublime text 2 google app engine code completion

Tags: google-app-engine, sublimetext2

just trying out sublime text and like it, but is there any way to customize it for use with google app engine? Would be nice to at least have code completion.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already using it, install [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) and then install [SublimeCodeIntel](http://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel). While not specifically for GAE, it provides intelligent code completion for any modules that are imported into your code. The initial run will take a while, as it has to index everything and GAE is quite large, but it'll definitely prove its worth as you use it. Take some time to browse through the [community packages](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community) for Package Control (as well as [wbond's own](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages)), as there's a lot of good stuff out there for ST2.

Once your code is ready to deploy, you can use the [`appcfg.py`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp) command line utility from the SDK in a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) along the lines of the following:

```
{
  "cmd": ["appcfg.py --option --other_option=foo update", "$project_path"],
  "path": "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine",
  "encoding": "UTF-8",
  "shell": true
}
```

where `$project_path` is an internal ST2 variable taken from your project settings (under the `Project` menu).

Comment: I've added the path to my google appengine library folder in the .codeintel/config file. My path is "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/lib". However, nothing happens as far as I can see. Do I have to manually start the indexing process? Maybe my path is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Adding the google_appengine folder to my sublime project did the trick. I don't know why adding the path to .codeintel/config doesn't work.

Comment: @dafeda - I haven't worked with GAE on Windows, so I'm not sure. Glad it's working, though! If you like my answer, please feel free to click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: I'm trying to set this up instead with `"dev_appserver.py --port=9090"`, the build finishes, but then if I try to load `localhost:9090`, it isn't running. What's missing?

Comment: @OllieFord I'm not sure. You should probably [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and reference this answer. Please include your complete build system, any other relevant information, and the results of running the command from the command line.

Comment: It worked for me by entering the path of every library under the `google_appenging/lib` folder, as well as the `google_appenging/lib` folder itself. I also made sure the path starts with `c:/` (note lowercase c).

Comment: @mattdmo     I am using Mac , Sublime Text 3. I wanna upload angular js application with Servlet code, via gulp task to GAE. Kindly guide me on it.

Comment: @Meenu if you have a new question, please [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it. Include as much information as possible, including all of the research you've done. Clearly state what you know, and what your *specific* question is. Remember that Stack Overflow is **not** a tutorial site, so your question as formulated in your comment will be closed as off-topic. You'll need to carefully read the GAE docs to try and answer your question first before asking.