# GAE dev_appserver build system for Sublime Text 3

Tags: google-app-engine, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879583/1446048) to instead use the development (local) app server, and I'm using Sublime Text 3 instead of 2, if there's any difference.

My current `GAE_dev.sublime-build` is:

```
{
    "working_dir": "$project_path",
    "cmd": ["sh", "-c", "dev_appserver.py", "--port=9090"],
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "shell": true
}
```

And the only output is:

```
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Visiting `localhost:9090` yields no success.

When I run (what I think is) the same command in Terminal:

```
$ cd /project/path
$ dev_appserver.py --port=9090
```

there's a load of output, the app is running at `:9090`, and due to the way in which `dev_appserver.py` works, it keeps running - which makes me highly suspicious of Sublime's 'Finished'.

I tried restarting Sublime as per [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266342/build-system-sublime-text-3), but it made no difference.

---

What crucial step have I missed?

Or even just to give me a kick in the right direction - is there a way to see Sublime's raw interaction with bash? So I can see exactly what command it issues, and what the response is?

Comment: You found a way for this? I am struck with same issue.

Comment: @Meenu No, sorry, I no longer use Sublime - I've found Atom more flexible and easier to use (and open source :)).

Comment: I used Atom too. How did you do GAE deployment in Atom.? Any package?

Comment: @Meenu Well I'm not currently using GAE, but typically I have a `term3` pane open, so I'd just run it 'manually'. There is the package `build` though.